# Best way to omit string constants from Release build

Tags: c++

### Question

What are the better approaches to removing certain string constants from the release build of a program?

### The problem

I'm working on a program and use `std::clog` for various debugging output to the console, such as `clog << "State change complete." << endl;` I noticed that in my release build that these string constants still show up in the compiled executable. What's the best way to address this problem? I'd like to not use macros if I can help it.

### Things I've tried/considered

I've considered using macros as a wrapper for the line of code (ex. `DEBUG(clog << "string");` I've tried using macros as a wrapper for the string constants (ex. `clog << DSTRING("State change complete.");`), and considered using a global constant (shudder) to wrap the code in an `if` condition, such as `if (falseIfRelease) { ... }`.

I've also considered storing the constants in a namespace in two separate files, one file for the debug build and the other for release, with the constants in the release build's file being empty strings. But that takes a lot of effort for writing out simple debug messages. Needless to say, I'm not very satisfied with these options.

Comment: Most compilers will have a list of predefined macros.  Look at their list for macros used for debugging, such as `NDEBUG`.

Comment: At my shop, we release debug builds.  This will allow us to debug issues found with the code without worrying about differences between debug and release builds.  We strip out the debug information before programming onto the platform.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, I'm familiar with the predefined macros. Those would've been my gotos for determining if my macros should be defined or not, but I'm looking for other solutions if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this trick in C++17: a macro that expands to an unfinished `if()` statement:

```
#include <iostream>

// Returns true iff we are logging with LOG().
inline constexpr bool isLogging() noexcept
{
  return
#if defined(NDEBUG)
    false
#else
    true
#endif
    ;
}

// Evaluate to an unfinished std::clog expression, or nothing at all.
#define LOG() if constexpr(isLogging()) std::clog

int
main()
{
  LOG() << "DEMO: This is a conditional string.\n";
  std::cout << "DEMO: This is always here.\n";
  LOG() << "DEMO: Exiting.\n";
}
```

Yes, it uses a macro (or two), but how else would you create half a statement?

Compile with `-DNDEBUG` and the `LOG()`-started statements melt away:

```
$ clang++-9 -std=c++17 -s -o prog main.cc && strings prog |grep DEMO
DEMO: This is a conditional string.
DEMO: This is always here.
DEMO: Exiting.
$ clang++-9 -std=c++17 -s -o prog main.cc -DNDEBUG && strings prog |grep DEMO
DEMO: This is always here.
```

You can use whatever macro or condition you want to decide how `isLoggable()` behaves.

The same trick works for a normal, non-`constexpr` conditional, too (but won't save you strings in the image that way).  You can make the macro `LOG(level)` and conditionally *evaluate* the expression only when logs at `level` would be emitted, which makes for a very cheap skipped debug-level log message, especially when combined with `__builtin_expect()`.